# Using Array and not ArrayList. User has to write the exact number of data that is provided by the array.

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, bluej

Using Array and not ArrayList. User has to write the exact number of data that is provided by the array. The error that I get is NullPointerException, For example, if my array Dinfo and array Linfo has 1, i only can write 1 data for each class. But if i put 100 for my array Dinfo and Linfo, i have to write 100 data so that my information will be shown. If not i will get a nullpointerexception.

```
    import java.util.*;
public class testMain
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String User;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Desktop[] Dinfo = new Desktop[100];
    Laptop[] Linfo = new Laptop[100];
    int D = 0;
    int L = 0;

    int A;
    int B;

    do
    {
        System.out.println("****************** Artificial Intelligence Co. **********");
        System.out.println("Computer Menu");  
        System.out.println("1. Add a new Desktop Information");
        System.out.println("2. Add a new Laptop Information");
        System.out.println("3. Display all Computer Information");
        System.out.println("4. Quit");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.print("Please enter either 1 to 4: "); 
        User =(scanner.nextLine());

        if (User.equals("1"))
        {
            Dinfo[D] = new Desktop();
            Dinfo[D].setDisplayDesktopInfo();
            D++;


        }

        else if (User.equals("2"))
        {

            Linfo[L] = new Laptop();
            Linfo[L].setDisplayLaptopInfo();
            L++;


         }

         else if(User.equals("3"))
         {
             for(A= 0; A < Dinfo.length; A++)
             {

                     System.out.println("=======================Desktop===========================");
                     Dinfo[A].getDisplayDesktopInfo();

                     System.out.println("");



             }

             for(B = 0; B < Linfo.length; B++)
             {

                     System.out.println("=======================Laptop============================");
                     Linfo[B].getDisplayLaptopInfo();

                     System.out.println("");


             }

         }


         else if(User.equals("4"))
         {
             System.out.println("Thank You!");
            }
    }
    while(!User.equals("4"));


}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `null` check in place:

```
if (Dinfo[A] != null) {
    Dinfo[A].getDisplayDesktopInfo();

    System.out.println("");
}
```

And similar for `Linfo[B]`.

Obviously, using an `ArrayList` is far easier.

Comment: Excuse me? Do you mean [overriding a method in Java](https://www.google.com/search?q=overriding+a+method+in+java)?

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException is

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:
>
> - Calling the instance method of a null object.
> - Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
> - Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
> - Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

So the easiest way to  avoid is  to  check for  null and then access the value of that reference / variable if it isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to worry about the predefined size of the area, you may declare the arrays like this: create arrays with dummy size of 1

```
Desktop[] Dinfo = new Desktop[1];
Laptop[] Linfo = new Laptop[1];
```

and then for selection 1, 2, ... you may do something like this:

```
 if (User.equals("1")) {
       Desktop[] temp = new Desktop[Dinfo.length+1];
       System.arraycopy( Dinfo, 0, temp, 0, Dinfo.length );
       Dinfo = temp
       Dinfo[D] = new Desktop();
       Dinfo[D].setDisplayDesktopInfo();
       D++;
    }
```

Finally, in order to print, do what `Robby Cornelissen` specified above.